# Visual Studio Code - halting a Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs, visual-studio-code

[This page explains](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) how you can start a task (e.g. a `Grunt` task):

but I don't see how you halt the task (i.e. the equivalent of doing `Ctrl C` from the CLI).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and search/select "Tasks: Terminate Running Task"

Or define a new keybinding for this. Go to File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts->keybindings.json and add:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate"
}
```